# project is missing required annotation processing library

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse IDE suddenly showed in Problem view saying "xxxx project is missing required annotation processing library: xxxx (some old jar in M2_REPO).
I googled and did not find any answers why my project is using the old jar and where the error comes from.

Answer (score 10):

To remove the error, right click project -> properties -> Java Compiler ->Annotation Processing-> Factory Path, uncheck Enable project specific settings. [image: Enable project specific settings]