# How to resolve Visual Studio Code 'project is missing required annotation processing library'

Tags: visual-studio-code, annotations

Visual Studio Code (v1.81.1) suddenly showed in Problem view saying "xxxx project is missing required annotation processing library: 'M2_REPO/org/apache/camel/camel-http/3.20.2/camel-http-3.20.2.jar'".
I have 106 repitions of this problem.

This is the same issue from Stack Overflow post [project is missing required annotation processing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214655/project-is-missing-required-annotation-processing-library). This does not seem to affect the outcome of the build, but it does hide any other problems. Searching for 'Annotation' in the management page did not return any useful results.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved: pom.xml files versions did not match the jar file versions for  org.apache.camel.springboot and org.apache.camel